# Preferences DataStore

Tags: kotlin, sharedpreferences

Estou cadastrando um usuario com preferences,
a ideia é ter um contador para usar como chave

minha dificuldade é achar o método que mostra a quantidade de usuário já cadastrado

```
suspend fun saveListUsers(user: User) {
    context.dataStore.edit { preferences ->
        var allUsers = preferences.METODO
        var key = allUsers.size + 1
        preferences[stringPreferencesKey(key)] = Gson().toJson(user)
    }
}
```

Alguém sabe me dizer se o Shared preference tem método que busca tudo que já foi cadastrado?
Pesquisei e só vi pessoal salvar e editar sempre na mesma chave

Answer (score -2):

Então, preference é somente para gravar uma informação do usuário que está acessando o sistema, e não gravar uma lista de usuários. Veja sobre Room pois é um SQLite melhorado onde você possa gravar listas de conteúdos como Senha, usuário e ID.

Answer (score -3):

Então, para descobrir a quantidade de usuários cadastrados em um SharedPreferences você precisaria recuperar cada usuário cadastrado e contar a quantidade que foi recuperado do SharedPreferences.

Ao meu ver, armazenar vários cadastros dessa maneira pode ter uma complexidade muito grande porque teria que ter cada chave de cada cadastro para recuperá-lo do SharedPreferences já que ele armazenada no formato chave-valor.

Uma abordagem que poderia utilizar é serializar a lista de usuários cadastrados em um gson e armazenar com uma única chave e sempre que for criar um novo usuário recuperar primeiro essa lista, serializar de volta para uma lista de objetos, adicionar o novo cadastro no final da lista, transformar novamente em gson e assim salvar novamente no Shared.

Outra opção que é muito mais comum para esse tipo de armazenamento é utilizando Banco de dados. No android você tem 3 opções de armazenamento local: o Room, o SQlite ou o Realm. Utilizando um deles acredito que faça mais sentido para o solução do seu problema do que a utilização do SharedPreferences.